# Converting to OOP code stopped working

Tags: php

I am trying to convert my functions file into an OOP file since I have been reading that its that way to go. I am still learning and am still confused about a lot in OOP but figured I would convert some things to help understand it better. I am running into some trouble right now trying to get data from my database. I am not getting anything printed to the screen, no error messages either. What did I do wrong?

```
<?php
require 'resources/library/DB.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$username = "test";
class userFunctions{
    public function checkLogin($conn,$username) {
    try{
       $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `userName`= :userName');
       $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $username);
       $stmt->execute();
       $salt = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
       return $salt;
}

}

$a = new userFunctions;


$a->checkLogin($conn, $username);

    echo $salt;


?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never assign anything to `$salt` (outside the class).

```
$salt = $a->checkLogin($conn, $username);
```

Also, you should be getting at least a notice. You echo `$salt` without ever having assigned anything to it. You should turn on all errors and notices when working on the code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Put it at the top of your script.

Comment: Excellent it worked thanks! I tried your recommendation on the `error_reporting(-1);` and I purposely broke the code again but still did not get any error or notice. It should print to the screen right? or is it stored in a log file I have to look at?

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Try `ini_set('display_errors', true);` as well. This should ensure the errors are output directly rather than logged.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is an even more fundamental programming concept than OOP: a function accepts certain input, and "returns" some output. That output is not put into any particular named variable, because the idea of a function is that you can reuse it in different parts of your code, for different purposes.

The line `return $salt;` states that the return *value* of the function is the value that the variable `$salt` has *at that point inside the function*. But you are then expecting `$salt` to exist outside the function as well.

You need to change this line:

```
$a->checkLogin($conn, $username);
```

to something that looks at what the `checkLogin` function returns, such as:

```
$salt_returned = $a->checkLogin($conn, $username);
echo $salt_returned;
```

(You can call it `$salt` if you like, but be aware that it's not the same variable that happened to be called `$salt` inside the function.)